# How to make a .com file using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, com

How can we make a .com file using C/C++? Is it possible?

Edit: I was able to successfully make a com file using darin's suggestions. But somehow the exe file of the following program cannot be converted to com file. I get the "File cannot be converted" message by exe2bin. I'm using Borland Turbo C++ 3.0. Any suggestions?

```
#include <dos.h>
void interrupt (*oldint65)( );
char st[80] = {"Hello World$"};
void interrupt newint65(void);
void main()
{
    oldint65 = getvect(0x65); 
    setvect(0x65, newint65);
    geninterrupt (0x65);
    geninterrupt (0x65);
    geninterrupt (0x65);
    setvect(0x65, oldint65);
}
void interrupt newint65( )
{
     _AH = 0x09;
     _DX=(unsigned int)st;
     geninterrupt (0x21);
}
```

Comment: Cause: The program to be converted has one of the following problems:

    * The program has an origin of 0100h but a different entry point.
    * The program requires segment fixups.
    * The program code and data are larger than 64 KB.
    * The program has more than one declared segment
    * The file is not a valid .EXE-format file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C, you must compile your program with the [TINY memory model](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/ctgMemoryModel.html). Then you can use use [EXE2BIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490635.aspx) or a similar program to convert an EXE file to a COM file.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on what you mean. Do you want to compile your program **into** a `.com` file? That would depend on your compiler, if it is possible at all.
If you are writing a compiler (or something like that), and want to produce a `.com` file from your **own** program, you should have a look at the [COM article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file), or use the [NASM](http://nasm.us) assembler to assemble to a `.com` file: `nasm -o hello.com hello.asm`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's probably worth pointing out that you seem to be doing TSR programming, which is unlikely to work fully or even properly on non-DOS (i.e. modern) operating systems such as Windows XP/Vista.

You might want to consider running a DOS emulator such as bochs, which also makes it easier to run legacy development tools such as TC++